# Visual Studio 2017 button for toggle .h and corresponding .cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

In Visual stdio 2013 there was a button to toggle between .h and corresponding .cpp files.  Is this button exist in Visual Studio 2017? ( i know the keyboard shortcut ctrl k+o but I'd prefer the button).

Comment: Where is this button in VS 2013? I can't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: It is be available (by default) in the editor context menu, if not then you may add that command to a toolbar (good luck to find it in the _Add Command_ window without a search feature...). If you installed the VS SDK you may have better time searching as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-commands

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a toolbar button however in the context menu when right clicking in a file there is a option of "Toggle Header / Code File" which does what you want.